# How to start big nodejs project virtual classroom?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nginx, redis

Developers i'm a nodejs developer with a experience of 1.5 years working in the company my question is i'm doing a project which is called a virtual classroom like a webinar platform where chat support, drawing and etc functionalities are available, so from last 2 month had been done of working in project i had gone through the each component directory and file with it's documents also they have used of docker, redis, proxy server, nginx, session, mongodb these kind of services and it's working fine on server end side but can't able to stablish on my local machine and it's a linux based project where have numbers of powershell files with PM2 library to make it run... so i followed a docs with some code also i success to make the service on and registered a local domain also in hosts file or nginx custom configuration it is working fine... but when i hit my ulr on browser with the local domain it not going to any of the route....

Example - like if we make a node simple project with hello world and it will working on 4500 port so we write localhost:4500 and it will print our responce on browser

but if the run my project through a PM2 or a simple node app.js bcoz this app.js have connected with all nodes services and virtual classroom and you the linux platform we don't need to make serivice on it's by default in runing state monogoDB, redis, docker, nginx but the real question is while firing the command node app.js it shows some json and told port:2178 but when in hit this on browser localhost:2178 not responce to GET request why??? but there is route called localhost:2178/landing/session/v1/classid(which is encrypted code) this url not working what to do ??

Comment: Sorry i can't give you any folder structure or any info because policies and privacy matters

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.